# Regression interpretation with logarithms

Tags: regression-coefficients, logarithm

In reference to this question: [interpreting level-log model that has a percentage variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283421/interpreting-level-log-model-that-has-a-percentage-variable)

If I have a regression equation: child_test_score = 400 + 25log(family_income)

Is this the correct interpretation:
A one percent increase in family_income is expected to increase child_test_score by 0.25 percentage points?

or

A one percent increase in family_income is expected to increase child_test_score by 0.25 points (0.25 units)?

or both? I tend to see the latter interpretation so I am wondering if the former interpretation is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+log+interpret*  found the duplicate -- and there are many more.  See, especially, [Graham Cookson's answer.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/551/919)